# Не печатается Hello, World!

Tags: c++, вывод, io, sizeof

Почему этот код не печатает "Hello, World!"?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(std::cout << "Hello, World!") << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When applied to an expression, `sizeof` does not evaluate the expression
>
> — [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)

Параметр `sizeof` не *вычисляется* (то есть никакие функции в нем не вызываются на самом деле, `=`, `++` и `--` не меняют значения переменных, и т. д.).

Потому что для определения размера это не нужно. Размер всегда известен во время компиляции. (Потому что зависит только от типа выражения, который тоже известен во время компиляции.)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы попросили его вывести размер *типа* выражения `std::cout << "Hello, World!"`, причем этот размер вычисляется во время компиляции, а не во время выполнения программы.

Смотрите, например, какая разница, чему будет равна переменная `int i;` - ее размер от этого не изменится. Так и

```
std::cout << "Hello, World!"
```

что бы вы ни выводили - будет иметь один и тот же возвращаемый тип, так что реально выполнять выражение совершенно ни к чему...

Посмотрите тут - https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ke45d7 - как видите, размер вычисляется и подставляется еще на уровне компиляции...